# how can I fill a data table variable value from class response in c#

Tags: c#

How can I pass retrieve class variable value to the `checkIn` form?

checkIn form: my question is: why is the `oldCheckInDt` variable still empty?

```
// assign variable 
DataTable oldCheckInDt = new DataTable();

private void btnUpdateCheckIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Retrieve.loadDataTable("sp_loadBasicCheckIn", oldCheckInDt, Convert.ToInt32(txtCheckInId.Text.Trim()));

    // my question - why is "oldCheckInDt"// still empty
}
```

Retrieve class:

```
public static void loadDataTable(string proc, DataTable tb, Int32 Id)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(proc, MainClass.con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            tb = dt;    // tb successfully filled with data.
        }
        else
        {
            tb = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MainClass.showMessage("Exception : " + ex, "error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code ? Does `tb = dt;` line of code execute?

Comment: Unrelated, but AddwithValue has some issues : https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: yes I debug it ! yes it execute. tb value has data inside in retrieve class, but inside the checkIn form it is empty.

Comment: Can you explain why a method called loadDataTable returns a void instead of the datatable loaded? If you assign your variable oldCheckInDt  to the returned table it will work

Comment: @Aron looks like data table assignment does not work this way... As suggested by Steve, you should return DataTable from the method. Assign the returned value to the `dt` in the form.

Comment: @steve thanks, sorry should I change method returns void to what ? i am new to c# thanks

Comment: @Steve `public static DataTable loadDataTable()`

Comment: @Charlieface yes, removed the comment, added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a DataTable in that way, the receiving method creates a new variable (called tb) in its stack and assign at that variable the reference to the memory where the line *DataTable oldCheckInDt = new DataTable();* created the initial table.
Now when you write *tb = dt;* you are changing the value of tb (it contains a reference) to a different reference (the value of dt) but the initial *oldCheckInDt* is unaffected by this operation. It still contains the original reference.

This is key point in programming. Understanding the difference between values and references is fundamental See: [Values vs Reference](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) and many more articles about this point.

However, to fast fix your code I think you should return the DataTable loaded in the loadDataTable method instead of trying to assign the loaded table to a parameter passed from the caller.

```
public static DataTable loadDataTable(string proc, Int32 Id)
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MainClass.Connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(proc, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = Id;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MainClass.showMessage("Exception : " + ex, "error");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in the calling code you could write

```
// assign variable 
DataTable oldCheckInDt = new DataTable();

private void btnUpdateCheckIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    oldCheckInDt ? Retrieve.loadDataTable("sp_loadBasicCheckIn", oldCheckInDt, Convert.ToInt32(txtCheckInId.Text.Trim()));
    if(oldCheckInDt!= null && oldCheckInDt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ....
    }    
    else
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Notice other changes made to the *loadDataTable* method. First of all is a common error to use a global connection object and keep it open for the lifetime of an application. Create/Use/Destroy is the best way to preserve resources and let the ADO.NET Connection Pooling do its dirty work for you to serve connections. Second, do not use AddWithValue because it has a subtle behavior with parameters of type Date, Decimals/Float or event strings. Better avoid it